# Meteor ms-seo static meta tags per route

Tags: meteor, seo, meta-tags

I cant get SEO settings to work on a route basis.

What I've tried:
1) Setting it globally in seotest.js above client or server code.

```
SeoCollection = new Meteor.Collection("SeoCollection");

Router.route('/', function () {
this.render('index');
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'index'
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'index',
            title: 'indexpagetestl',
            meta: {
                'description': 'Manuel Schoebel is an experienced web developer and startup founder. He develops but also consults startups about internet topics.'
            },
            og: {
                'title': 'About - Manuel Schoebel',
                'image': 'http://manuel-schoebel.com/images/authors/manuel-schoebel.jpg'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);

Router.route('/notindex', function () {
this.render('notindex');
SeoCollection.update(
    {
        route_name: 'notindex'
    },
    {
        $set: {
            route_name: 'notindex',
            title: 'notindexpagetestl',
            meta: {
                'description': 'Manuel Schoebel is an experienced web developer and startup founder. He develops but also consults startups about internet topics.'
            },
            og: {
                'title': 'About - Manuel Schoebel',
                'image': 'http://manuel-schoebel.com/images/authors/manuel-schoebel.jpg'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);
}
```

I've also tried to same code inside (Meteor.isClient) and (Meteor.isServer) code, but neither works.

I am able to get the initial SEO meta tags working with:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if(Meteor.isClient){
        return SEO.config({
            title: 'Manuel Schoebel - MVP Development',
            meta: {
                'description': 'Manuel Schoebel develops Minimal Viable Producs (MVP) for Startups'
            },
            og: {
                'image': 'http://manuel-schoebel.com/images/authors/manuel-schoebel.jpg'
            }
        });
    }
});
```